# how to download file cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp

I have 4 different types of file to download image/doc/pdf/xls. I want to download the file once I clicked on file link.

//controller

```
public function sendFile($id) {
    $file = $this->Attachment->getFile($id);
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
    // Return response object to prevent controller from trying to render
    // a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

//view

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->response->file($file->path); ?>"><?php echo $file->name; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to return the response - see [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2).
Simply use

```
public function send_file($id = null) {
    ...
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
}
```

In your view you need to link to this controller action, though (if you think about it):

```
$this->Html->link('Download', array(
    'controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'send_file', $id
));
```

Also note the conventions I corrected for you - the docs tell you that as well.

Answer (score 0):

just to complete and add some notes on Mark's answer

Simply use

```
public function send_file($file_name = null) {
    //local machine to the file
    //e.g. c:\wamp\www\project\...
    $path_local = 'path to the file'.$file_name;

    //live path to the file
    //e.g. \var\...
    $path_live = 'path to the file'.$file_name;

    $this->autoRender = false;
    //if you trying to test it from localhost set the localhost path 
    //other wise live path
    $this->response->file($path_live or $path_local, array('download' => true));
}
```

In your view you need to link to this controller action, though (if you think about it):

```
$this->Html->link('Download', array(
    'controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'send_file', $file_name
));
```

Also note the conventions I corrected for you - the docs tell you that as well.

Comment: That can easily break as a filename can contain invalid URL chars. It should be a slug or a unique id then. Or query strings should be used.

Comment: I am going to use unique query string. thank you for your response.